# Prove $\operatorname{Gal}(M_3/M_1)\cong\operatorname{Gal}(M_2/(M_1\cap M_2))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group, galois-extensions

I've been solving problems from my Galois Theory course, and I got the idea to solve this one but I'm unable to prove some details. The problem goes like this:

> Being $L/K$ a Galois extension, and being $M_1/K$ and $M_2/K$ Galois
> subextensions. Prove that, if $M_3$ is the smallest subfield of $L$
> which contains $M_1$ and $M_2$, then $\operatorname{Gal}(M_3/M_1)\cong
>  \operatorname{Gal}(M_2/(M_1\cap M_2))$.

After thinking about it and drawing the corresponding Hasse diagram, I concluded the isomorphism between those Galois groups is
$$\varphi:\operatorname{Gal}(M_3/M_1)\longrightarrow \operatorname{}Gal(M_2/(M_1\cap M_2))$$
$$ \sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(M_3/M_1) \implies \varphi(\sigma)=\sigma|_{M_2} $$
Now I need to prove it's an isomorphism, so I need to prove it's well defined, it's a homomorphism and it's a bijection. My problem is that I'm unable to prove some of these. Here's what I already did:

1. **Well defined**: Being $\sigma\in Gal(M_3/M_1)$, it was easy to prove that $\sigma|_{M_2}(\lambda)=\lambda$, $\forall\lambda\in (M_1\cap M_2)$. However, I don't really know how to prove $\sigma|_{M_2}$ is an automorphism in $M_2$ (this may be trivial, but I'm not sure how to prove it).
2. **Homomorphism**: this one was obvious I think, because it's trivial that, being $\sigma,\tau\in \operatorname{Gal}(M_3/M_1)$, then $$\sigma \circ\tau|_{M_2} = \sigma|_{M_2}\circ\tau|_{M_2}.$$
3. **Bijection**: I thought the easiest way to prove this last one was first proving it's injective and then prove $|\operatorname{Gal}(M_3/M_1)|=|\operatorname{Gal}(M_2/(M_1\cap M_2))|$ (I assumed I would be able to prove it by degree transitivity but now I'm not sure if I can do it with just the hypothesis that $M_3$ is the smallest field that contains $M_1$ and $M_2$). However, I couldn't prove any of these statements (maybe surjectivity is easier to prove than $|\operatorname{Gal}(M_3/M_1)|=|\operatorname{Gal}(M_2/(M_1\cap M_2))|$, I don't know).

How can I finish this exercise? Is what I already did correct? Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows directly form [your recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152160/prove-galel-e-is-a-galois-extension-in-this-case/4152282#4152282) since $M_3=M_1M_2\subseteq L$ (assuming that all extensions are finite; but as you are talking about the order of the groups I think you have this case in mind too).

What you did reiterates the proof of the theorem I linked and is correct so far. The only difficult part left is surjectivity. If this part is not clear to you I can try to formulate it explictly.

Comment: I realised it was pretty similar, but didn't realised $M_3=M_1M_2$ (in my head, it was something more complicated involving sums instead of just products). And isn't proving $|Gal(M_3/M_1)|=|Gal(M_2/(M_1\cap M_2))|$ easier than proving surjectivity? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso The compositum is *by definition* the smallest field containing $M_1$ and $M_2$ (equivalently, containing $M_1\cup M_2$; that's the whole idea) which is then necessarily contained in $L$. Writing it as $M_1M_2$ might be a bit misleading though. For the second part: It depends, I think. From my experience showing that the orders conincide is usually easier when you work with some concrete field extension while in the general case the good old injective $+$ surjective proof is easier.

Comment: So $M_3$ isn't exactly the field of elements $ab$ such that $a\in M_1$ and $b\in M_2$ as $M_3=M_1M_2$ suggests? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso No, it's not! This set would not be a field as we are lacking additive closure. Glad to be of help! Make sure to accept the answer if you've no further questions (the same goes for your other questions by the way). :)